# starting redis server from jvm using process buildser

Tags: java, bash, redis, processbuilder

I have installed redis 3.0.7  using

```
sudo yum install -y gcc-c++

wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.7.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-3.0.7.tar.gz

sudo make -C redis-3.0.7/deps lua hiredis linenoise
sudo make -C redis-3.0.7 MALLOC=libc install
```

the above command were run from a jmv using, the code below.

after redis-server is available on the command line

I can ssh onto all of my boxes and run redis-server  which starts a redis instance.

however when I try and use the redis-server command from java

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    int exitCode = p.exitValue();

    BufferedReader reader;
    if (exitCode != 0 ){
        System.out.println("ERROR exit code = "+p.exitValue()+" cmd="+command);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    }else{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    }
```

I get and error

```
  ERROR exit code = 1 cmd=nohup redis-server >> out.txt 2>&1 & echo $!
```

if I try

```
    sudo nohup redis-server >> out.txt 2>&1 & echo $!
```

I get cmd not found error.

what trick's am i missing hear ?